# How to get text from a node value using PHP DOMDocument

Tags: php, regex, domdocument

I am trying to loop through nodeValues of objects outputed by DOMDocument and get the text output but I am not sure how to go about doing it. My code and output are below.

From the output below I need to get only the NodeValue text output, e.g. "Bar and Hotel".

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
                @$dom->loadHTML($v);

                $xpath = new DomXpath($dom);
                $div = $xpath->query('//*[@class="type-cat"]'); 
                foreach ($div as $a) {

                    var_dump($a );      
                }

object(DOMElement)#22 (18) { 
    ["tagName"]=> string(2) "h5"
    ["schemaTypeInfo"]=> NULL
    ["nodeName"]=> string(2) "h5"
    ["nodeValue"]=> string(41) " Bar and Hotel" 
    ["nodeType"]=> int(1)
    ["parentNode"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" 
    ["childNodes"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" 
    ["firstChild"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)"
    ["lastChild"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)"
    ["previousSibling"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)"
    ["nextSibling"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" 
    ["attributes"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" 
    ["ownerDocument"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" 
    ["namespaceURI"]=> NULL 
    ["prefix"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["localName"]=> string(2) "h5" 
    ["baseURI"]=> NULL
    ["textContent"]=> string(41) " Bar and Hotel" 
}
```

Comment: Try: `var_dump($a->nodeValue);`

Comment: Surely [TFM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php) contains what you need

Comment: `var_dump($a->textContent)` if you just need the text output

Comment: Regarding the tag assigned to this question, its not a good idea to use [tag:RegEx] to extract from HTML... **[Here's why.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/8112776)**

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from the dump of the node object, the nodeValue is what you are looking for. You access it with

```
$a->nodeValue;
```

Depending on the nodeType property this will return the text value.

You find this and all other public accessible properties and methods here:

http://www.php.net/manual/de/class.domnode.php